# UITest tap not working on iOS 12.4 using iPhone X (works on iPhone 7)

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

Could this be related to SafeArea issues in iOS12.4 (and actually 12.2 as well)?
I use the following function to tap a view during my UITests.

```
func tapAtLocation(_ element: XCUIElement) -> Self {
    let loc = element.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: .init(dx: 0, dy: 0))
    loc.tap()
    return self
}
```

I try to tap at the location of a specific image.
So I get the image and trigger a tap

```
let myImage = App.images[myImageViewIdentifier].firstMatch
tapAtLocation(myImage)
```

It works on new iOS versions and also on iPhone 7 iOS 12.4 but not on iPhone X.
And I need it to work on iPhone X :)

What do you propose me to do? Maybe you have a nice debugging trick to see exactly where it tries to tap ?

Answer (score 0):

ok ! After a day of fail and retry, a simple solution worked out!

```
func tapAtLocation(_ element: XCUIElement) -> Self {
    let loc = element.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: .init(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.5))
    loc.tap()
    return self
}
```

This works on all devices (iPhone X, 7 and 11) with iOS 12.4 and 13+